# how to plot markers for same addresses but different suites in google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, marker

I know it doesn't make a lot of sense, but I have a map that plots all the addresses but there are places that share addresses like there is a Doctor's office in the suite 13 and a medical lab in suite 33. Doctors' office has red colored markers, medical lab has blue marker. They both have the exact same street address. How can I capture both in the google map? Right now, the latest one is plotted in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For obvious reasons Google Maps can't display two markers at exactly the same location on a 2D screen :) You probably want to merge these markers into one marker before building your map. For example, if you are pulling these addresses from a database, you could merge entries that share a street address and then generate the map. IIRC you can also use a custom marker image, so you could use one that's 50% red, 50% blue?

Comment: Yeap, mixed marker makes a lot of sense to me too, although implementation can be a little tricky